# How to test ConfigurationProperties in Spring with JUnit?

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-test

I have a `ConfigurationProperties` class and want to test it using `junit`. But the object is always `null`. What might be missing in the following code?

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
@EnableConfigurationProperties(MyProperties.class)
public class AppConfig {

}

@Service
public class MyService {
    @Autowired
    private MyProperties props;

    public void run() {
        props.getName();
    }
}

@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "my")
public class MyProperties {
    private String name;
    //getter,setter
}
```

**application.properties:**

```
my.name=test
```

**test:**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = {MyService.class,  MyProperties.class},
            includeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(value = {MyService.class,  MyProperties.class},
            type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE),
            lazyInit = true
)
@PropertySources(
        @PropertySource("application.properties")
    )
class AppTest {
    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertiesResolver() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }
}

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = ApplicationConfigTest.class)
public class MyTest extends AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests {
    @Autowired
    private MyService service;

    @Test
    public void testService() {
        service.run();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The following will load it for you:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = Application.class, initializers = ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.class)
```

Comment: In current Spring Boot versions `ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer` is deprecated, but in docs they said that we should use `ConfigDataApplicationContextInitializer` instead.